The next frog who has not yet jumped, jumps to the next available lily. Is the amount of frogs with a frog directly in front of them preserved?
Suppose there are $n$ frogs, all on (not necessarily adjacent) lily pads in a straight line. Starting with the leftmost frog, the next frog who hasn't jumped yet jumps to the next available (i.e. having no frog on it) lily pad to their right. Each frog jumps once. Are the amount of frogs who had a frog directly to the right of them at the start equal the amount of frogs who had a frog directly to the right of them at the end? To frame the question mathematically:
Let $S$ be some finite set of natural numbers.  Following the procedure to construct $T$:
$$\begin{array} {l}
T := \emptyset \\
\text{for each } k \in S, \text{ in increasing order:} \\
\quad \text{let }j\text{ be the smallest natural number satisfying} \\
\quad\quad     k < j \not \in T \cup S \\
\quad \text{insert }j \text{ into } T \\
\text{Ouput } T
\end{array}$$
Define $c(Z)$ to be the number of frogs with a neighbor to their right, in $Z$ that is
$$c(Z) = |\{n \text{ s.t. } \{n, n+1\} \subseteq Z\}|$$
Trying to prove $c(S) = c(T)$

You are using some really bad variable naming.  You are using $A$ to refer to a sequence of sequences, and $a$ to elements of $A$ in the definition, and then $a$ to refer to choices from the previous $a$, and then $a_i'$ to refer to things not in the previous $a$.  There are other letters in the alphabet.

What's the source of this problem? It could well be from a contest (not atypical for contests!), in which case describing the source becomes particularly important as we have a strict policy not to discuss problems from on-going contests.

Oh, small correction, the $a_i'$ refers to an element not in $a$, but not the previously defined $a$ but the one before that.

I tried to rewrite the formalism more clearly, please check it if is the intended meaning.

I wrote a program to check.  It is able to verify this is true for the first 50 million natural number sets in 7.1s on my computer : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e08524b0489314f0189d18c3bdd12767  Assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly anyway.

@Jyrki This is not a contest problem. The source of the problem is my interest in greedy algorithm procedures with subsets of natural numbers. And yes the re-formulation of the problem is correct I think. And an improvement of clarification.

Call a maximally sized contiguous subset of $S$ a "family" of frogs.  For example $S=\{2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13\}$, there are 3 families: $\{2, 3\}$, $\{6, 7\}$, and $\{10, 11, 12, 13\}$.  $\{11, 12\}$ is not a family because it isn't maximal.
Also, call the maximally contiguous subsets of $\overline S$ gaps, not counting any that come before the first family, but also including $\{\max S + 1 \dots \infty\}$ .  So the gaps of $S$ are $\{4, 5\}$, $\{8, 9\}$, and $\{14, 15, 16, \dots \infty\}$.  $\{0, 1\}$ is not counted because it comes before $\{2, 3\}$.
Because $|S| = |T|$, it is sufficient to show that the number of families in $S$ and $T$ are equal.  The equality follows from:

The numbers of gaps in $S$ equals the number of families in $S$
Each family of $T$ is a subset of a gap of $S$
Each gap of $S$ has at most 1 family of $T$
Each gap of $S$ has at least 1 family of $T$

The first follows by definition.  The second by loop invariant.  The third follows from how elements are inserted without skipping.  The fourth follow from how each element of $S$ is transformed into a larger element in $T$.

+1, excellent answer!
